# Why is this showing an error?

Tags: errors

This is the error message I get for the line `\end{equation}`

```
You can't use `\eqno' in vertical mode.
\endequation ->\eqno 
                     \hbox {\@eqnnum }$$\@ignoretrue 
l.19 \end{equation}
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's impossible to say without seeing the code that generates the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have some code equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
1=2  
$$

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You can not have `$$` or a blank line inside the `equation`.

As above it produces

```
! You can't use `\eqno' in vertical mode.
\endequation ->\eqno 
                     \hbox {\@eqnnum }$$\@ignoretrue 
l.10 \end{equation}
```

Delete the `$$` and blank line

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
1=2  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

runs without error.